# Is it possible to kill enemies using the Sparrow hover bike?

Tags: destiny

I've just started playing Destiny, and have been trying to use my Sparrow hover bike to kill enemies by ramming them, but it just pushes them aside and I usually end up getting shot off the vehicle.

Does the hover bike support upgrades over time so that we can use it to kill enemies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to run over enemies with the Sparrow, but it is difficult.  Here is a video of it being done in a Crucible match:

**Note:**  This functionality is no limited to the Crucible.  I've run over enemies while patrolling as well as during missions.

Comment: Cool.  So he ran over a level-8 player, what is his level?  I couldn't see it anywhere.

Comment: Level doesn't matter in crucible @Alan.

Comment: As an added comment from experience, you can also splatter your teammates--in PvE, at least. (I haven't tried PvP yet so I'm not sure about this.)

Comment: You'll do extra damage if you can jam an enemy or friend into the geometry as well, like in a corner.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an upgrade for the sparrow which allows it to fire a weapon. However, that does not mean you cannot kill anything with it.

You can kill mobs and teammates with the sparrow. To do this, you need to be at max speed, and need to directly hit them. The sparrow itself does not do any damage at this point. When you strike the teammate or mob they are hurled at speed. If they hit something they take the same type of damage as fall damage. This is how you can kill them, I have done it to both mobs and teammates (whoops!).

tldr; Causing a teammate or mob to hit an object by hitting them into it with your sparrow can cause damage or kill them. There is no firing option.

Answer (score 1):

You can get off the sparrow and shoot the back engine, this will either have it blow up or shoot off toward the enemy in a straight line and detonate. Works as well as running them over.